# Passing structure to thread using _beginthreadx

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;
HANDLE ghEvents;


struct DataStructure
{
int r[2];
int h;
};


unsigned __stdcall f2(void *p)
{

DataStructure *input = (DataStructure *)p;
int i = (int)input->h;
cout <<i<<endl;

}   


int main()
{

HANDLE hThread[8];
DWORD i, dwEvent, dwThreadID;
unsigned threadID;
DataStructure input;

ghEvents = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);  

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{   
input.h=i;
hThread[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, f2, (void*)&input, 0, &threadID );
}

dwEvent = WaitForMultipleObjects(8,hThread,TRUE,INFINITE);       

CloseHandle(ghEvents); 
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{
CloseHandle( hThread[i] );
}

cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

The output is 77777777 instead of 12345678.

I know i have to pass the input by value and not reference but it keeps giving me an error message, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Compiling says that f2 needs to return a value. Also, your formatting has no indentation.

Comment: You have 2 options, one is to add a Wait for a event after you create one thread, that is signaled after the thread copys tha value of input->h, and the other is to create one DataStructure for each thread.

Comment: Can somebody reposnd to the new query i posted under ed heal's response ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is subsequent to my previous answer as is a better solution if the number of threads is known at compile time.

```
DataStructure input[8];  

... 

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)   
{     
   input[i].h=i;  
   hThread[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, f2, (void*)&input[i], 0, &threadID );  
}
```

And you need to return a value:

```
unsigned __stdcall f2(void *p)      
{      

   DataStructure *input = (DataStructure *)p;      
   int i = input->h;      
   cout <<i<<endl;      
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: My problem is only h value changes, there's another value i need to send to the function that reads 512 characters from a text file, instead of opening it in the function each time i though i could send it through this way, but you're asking me to refill those value each time into a new data structure, what's the best way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving each thread the address of the same `DataStructure`. Your output is non-deterministic. Depending on when each thread gets to run, they may read before, during, or after another iteration of that loop. Meaning, by the time the thread spins up and gets to access `input->h`, the main thread may have already continued on and changing `input.h` to the next iteration.

Example:

- Main - Loop iteration 0 sets `input.h` to 0.
- Main - Loop iteration 0 starts Thread 0 with `input` as a parameter.
- Main - Loop iteration 1 sets `input.h` to 1.
- Main - Loop iteration 1 starts Thread 1 with `input` as a parameter.
- Main - Loop iteration 2 sets `input.h` to 2.
- Main - Loop iteration 2 starts Thread 2 with `input` as a parameter.
- Thread 1 - Starts up.
- Thread 0 - Starts up.
- Main - Loop iteration 3 sets `input.h` to 3.
- Thread 0 - Reads `input->h` as 3.
- Thread 2 - Starts up.
- Main - Loop iteration 3 starts Thread 3 with `input` as a parameter.
- Thread 1 - Reads `input->h` as 3.
- Thread 3 - Starts up.
- Main - Loop iteration 4 sets `input.h` to 4.
- Thread 3 - Reads `input->h` as 4.
- Thread 2 - Reads `input->h` as 4.
- Thread 4 - Starts up.
- Thread 4 - Reads `input->h` as 4.

Final Output: 3344

Give each thread a different `DataStructure` so that they are not trying to read from the same memory address. This way, there is no race-condition. The term refers to the fact that thread start up and order of execution is not guaranteed, so if threads are accessing the same resources without synchronization being done, they will "race".

Comment: Note: Giving each thread a different `DataStructure` will fix the race condition for reading from `input->h`, but order is still not guaranteed. You've only guaranteed that each thread created will have a unique number. You'll see how non-deterministic thread execution ordering is. If you want to know how to get these threads to print in order, I can give a sample, though be warned that this will run *slower* than if you had simply called `f2` directly in your main thread's `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the data structure for each of the threads as you are overwriting the value of input.h for each of the threads.

So to fix, change it to

```
DataStructure *input; 

...

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
{    
   input = new DataStructure ;
   input->h=i; 
   hThread[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, f2, (void*)input, 0, &threadID ); 
}
```

And to avoid a memory leak get the f2 function to delete the input i.e.

```
unsigned __stdcall f2(void *p)     
{     

   DataStructure *input = (DataStructure *)p;     
   int i = input->h;     
   cout <<i<<endl;     
   delete input;
   return 0;
}
```

**note** This solution uses dynamic memory allocation as is good solution if the number of threads are unknown at compile time. See my other answer if the number of threads is known.

Comment: If the number of threads is known at compile time: make that number a constant variable with a numeric literal to initialize it, declare an array of `DataStructure` of that size. Try to avoid unnecessary dynamic memory and raw pointers. Emphasis on unnecessary, if unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

First point is:

You have no synchronization in place for your datastructure which is being passed to multiple threads, and while these threads are doing something with it, you're already going through the next iteration of the loop and *changing* the value of your datastructure.

Create a new datastructure inside a the loop to avoid having synchronization issues.